# Given matrix $A$ that is $4\times3$ and has $rank=2$ , let $u,v$ be different solutions to $Ax=c$ what is the solutions set?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given matrix $A$ that is $4\times3$ and has $rank=2$ , let $u,v$ be different solutions to $Ax=c$ what is the solutions set?
>
> a. $\{au+bv|a,b \in \Bbb R\}$
>
> b. $\{au+(1-a)v|a \in \Bbb R\}$ (this is the correct answer)
>
> c. $\{au+v|a \in \Bbb R\}$

the solution set for $Ax=c$ is $\{w+v|w \in P(A)\}$ while $P(A)$ is the solution space of $Ax=0$ according to dimension theorem formula we have $dimP(A)=3 - \rho(A)$ we know that $\rho(A)=2=rank$ so $dimP(A)=1$ we also know that if $u$ and $v$ are solutions then $u-v$ is also a solution for $Ax=0$ therefore $P(A)=Sp\{u-v\}$ I got stuck here so I tried a different approach and also got stuck

I tried making matrix $A$ according to the given information so
$$A= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&x&y&u\\
  0&1&z&v\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}
\right) $$

from here I got $a+bx+dy=u$ and $b+zd=v$ but again I did not know how to continue and it felt like it is not leading to anyplace.

I know this question is simple but I am having difficulty with questions of this type and trying to understand it all from the beginning.

thanks for any help and tips!

Comment: The dimension of the solution set to a consistent system $Ax=c$ will always equal $\text{nullity}(A)$. Since $\text{nullity}(A)=1$ the solution set in question will necessarily be a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$ . This rules out $(a)$. Option $(c)$ isn't valid since taking $a=1$ doesn't even provide you with a solution. So it's $(b)$

Comment: @MatthewH. appreciate the quick reply and help , wouldn't those reasons also mean that $(b)$ is not correct? 
and what way would you recommend if I wanted to get to the solution $(b)$ without eliminating other options?

Comment: The set in $(b)$ is the line connecting $u$ and $v$. You can verify directly that any point on this line is a solution to your consistent system

Comment: @MatthewH. can you please explain what you mean by that? I am sorry for the question I just didn't understand or how can i verify this by substitution if that is what you mean?